# Distinguishing between invalid raster files and valid ones at using arcpy functions

Tags: arcpy, esri-grid-format

I am trying to move raster files from one location to another.

By using the function: [ListRasters (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1%20/index.html#//018v0000003w000000), I can get the list of rasters to be moved, but the problem is that even corrupted rasters are listed by this function. Actually if you use ArcCatalog and navigate to the folder, everything seems to be right and valid and invalid rasters are listed together but if you try to preview a corrupted one, it will pop-up:

[image]

In detail, I am talking here about several corrupted Esri GRID rasters. How to differentiate them?

So, when I use the function: [Copy (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000051000000), arcpy rises an error when trying to move an invalid GRID.

I was trying to solve this issue by using any of the properties of the Describe function: [Describe object properties (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Describe_object_properties/018v00000013000000/), and getting any difference between the valid ones and the invalid ones, but this function raises an error on invalid datasets, so it cannot be used.

```
for raster in arcpy.ListRasters():
  desc = arcpy.Describe(raster)

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 1200, in Describe
return gp.describe(value)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 374, in describe
self._gp.Describe(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
IOError: "raster" does not exist
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use try-except in your code.

```
try:
    for raster in arcpy.ListRasters():
      desc = arcpy.Describe(raster)
except:
    'Do nothing, just skip to the next
```

If this isn't working you need to check if the raster exists first.

Comment: Good!, working so far, but is there any way of asking specifically for an invalid raster? is there any arcpy function to check this?

Comment: There are an infinite number if ways to destroy data, and no reliable ways to verify integrity. Catching exceptions on failure is your only option, and it will only capture *some* classes of error.

Comment: Errors, or invalid rasters are 'catched' by the except statement. You can handle them over there.

Comment: Yes, and not..The except statement will tell you that the "raster" does not exist as in the example above, but it is not true at all. It's there but it is not readable, that's different.

Comment: If it's listed in the catalog, then it's "there" but if it fails an *exists* **or** fails to describe, then it's corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

improved the algorithm so that it allows to handle all rasters, not only for the first exception

```
for raster in arcpy.ListRasters():
    try:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(raster)
    except:
        'Do nothing, just skip to the next
```